# Syntax Error Unexpected Token, React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a `Login` screen. When I press on a blue Text, I want it to navigate to the `Register` screen. 
However, it always shows me the same `Syntax Error: Unexpected Token`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Register from './src/screens/Register';

export default class Login extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Welcome',
}

navigateToRegister = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');
}

render() {
  return (
      <ScrollView style={{padding: 20}}>
          <Text
              style={{fontSize: 27}}>
              Login
          </Text>
          <TextInput placeholder='Username' />
          <TextInput placeholder='Password' />
          <View style={{margin:7}} />
          <Button
                  onPress={this.props.onLoginPress}
                  title="Submit"
              />
          <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}
              onPress={ this._navigateToRegister }
              Register
          </Text>
          </ScrollView>
      );

}
}
const App = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Register: { screen: Register },
  Secured: { screen: Secured },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

Comment: Just correct your `navigateToRegister` method  name is   `onPress={ this.navigateToRegister }`  it will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have and syntax error in code.

> second last text is not having closing angle bracket `>`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text, TextInput, View, Button } from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Register from "./src/screens/Register";

export default class Login extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Welcome"
  };

  navigateToRegister = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Register");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 27 }}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="Username" />
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" />
        <View style={{ margin: 7 }} />
        <Button onPress={this.props.onLoginPress} title="Submit" />
        <Text
          style={{ color: "blue" }}
          onPress={this._navigateToRegister}
          Register
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const App = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Register: { screen: Register },
  Secured: { screen: Secured }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);
```

> you can setup prettier and eslint they will provide you syntax error straight white editing code so that you don't need to waist time on finding this kinda errors.
>   [This is good guide to setup everything](https://hackernoon.com/configure-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vs-code-for-react-development-c9d95db07213)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered to mistakes in your code

1. You have used this._navigateToRegister function in onPress and defined navigateToRegister as a function.
2. And you forgot to close Text tag

```js
<Text
    style={{ color: "blue" }}
    nPress={this._navigateToRegister}>
```